# cordova android app rejected from google play error TrustManager

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I'm using cordova to create android app and I'm using com.comscoreplugin,cordova-plugin-google-analytics,cordova-plugin-audioinput,cordova-plugin-media,org.apache.cordova.plugin.ActivityIndicator,cordova-plugin-compat,cordova-plugin-network-information,org.apache.cordova.speech.speechrecognition,cordova-plugin-device,cordova-plugin-webrtc,cordova-plugin-dialogs,cordova-plugin-whitelist. I could build release apk file but when submit the apk to play store it's getting rejected error called TrustManger as below image 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhjvB.png). I tried submitting apk several time. It would be pleasure if some one can help me.thank you

Comment: Make sure that you are on the latest of all of those plugins. If you are, you will need to identify which of those plugins implements a custom `TrustManager`, then stop using that plugin.

Comment: No I couldn't find any TrustManager @CommonsWare.

Comment: refer this link https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016?hl=en